Trouble with Enemy Behavior in Unity Using NavMeshAgent and Physics OverlapBox
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class myScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    NavMeshAgent enemy;
    public Transform target; // target = player
    public Transform[] waypoints;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        enemy = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();

    }

    int index;
    public Vector3 Chasedistance;

    public bool playerisSpotted;
    public bool isOnserach;
    void Update()
    {
        
        Collider[] collsiders = Physics.OverlapBox(transform.position, Chasedistance);
        foreach (Collider col in collsiders)
        {
            if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
            {

                playerisSpotted= true;
                break;
            }

        }
        Determine_Behavior();
        
    }


    void Determine_Behavior()
    {
        void PatrolWaypoints()
        {


            enemy.SetDestination(waypoints[index].position);
            if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, waypoints[index].position) < 1)
            {
                index = (index + 1) % waypoints.Length;

            }
            return;
        }
        void MoveToPlayer()
        {
            enemy.SetDestination(target.position);
            return;
        }

        if (playerisSpotted)
        {
            MoveToPlayer();
        }
        else
        {
            PatrolWaypoints();
        }

    }




    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireCube(transform.position, Chasedistance);
    }
}

I'm working on implementing enemy behavior in Unity using the NavMeshAgent component for navigation and physics-based detection using OverlapBox. However, I'm encountering issues with the enemy's behavior, specifically regarding player detection and waypoint patrolling.
its also good to mention that when i tried to check in the inspector the bool "playerisspotted" it made the enemy go torwards the destination of the player so i think the issue is how i used the bool but i dont know what's wrong

So I see a couple of statements like trouble with .. or i think the issue is how i used .. and I'm encountering issues with .. ... But what exactly is that issue(s)? Please be precise and specific. It is not enough to just provide a script and let people here figure out ourselves what might possibly go wrong

my enemy navsmesh doesnt cast the Moveplayer() mehod and it keeps patrolling even when the player is inside the overlap area, its also worth mentioning that i have a collider to the player game object as well as tag named "Player" attached to it

navmeshes dont usually call thhings.. You moveplayer is also a local function to determine_behavior.. so.

so what do you suggest?

Are you sure target is referencing the correct object? Why not rather store it when actually spotting the player? if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) target = col.transform; (this would even generalize it more to also work in multiplayer situations) .. and what exactly is resetting playerisSpotted= false .. since it is public I have to assume another class might be disturbing it
